# TypeScript hybrid type implementation

Tags: typescript, hybrid

On http://www.typescriptlang.org/Handbook#interfaces website Hybrid Types are explained. As these are extremely helpful for creating typings to JS - I wonder if it's possible to define a class implementing e.g. such interface:

```
interface Counter {
    (start: number): string;
    interval: number;
    reset(): void;
}
```

If not then maybe it's possible to create just an object of that type? How?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I wonder if it's possible to define a class implementing

No

> If not then maybe it's possible to create just an object of that type?

Yes. There will be some use of a type assertion (or `any`):

```
interface Counter {
    (start: number): string;
    interval: number;
    reset(): void;
}

function getCounter():Counter{
    var counter = <Counter>function(start:number){};
    counter.interval = 123;
    counter.reset = function(){};
    return counter;
}
```

Comment: The example on the site not working with this code, can you include a sample usage with this?

Answer (score 1):

I think the more updated version is this:

```js
interface Counter {
  (start: number): string;
  interval: number;
  reset(): void;
}

function getCounter(): Counter {
  return (() => {
    var result: any = (start: number) => "Start!";
    result.result = 10;
    result.reset = () => {}
    //Converts the temporary variable to the interface type.
    return <Counter> result;
  })();
}
```