# Typescript - Hybrid Types

Tags: javascript, typescript

I see this example in the Typescript handbook:

```
interface Counter {
    (start: number): string;
    interval: number;
    reset(): void;
}

var c: Counter;
c(10);
c.reset();
c.interval = 5.0;
```

But when I try to do `c(10);` or set `c.interval = 5.0` I get an error -
*Cannot set property 'interval' of undefined*

I know I can do:

```
var c: Counter;
c = function(s: number){
 return "'" + s + "'";
}
```

What's missing - (or is this an incomplete example) ?

**Update:**

[There is  a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25340601/typescript-hybrid-type-implementation?rq=1) - which answers this question, although, I still find this example convoluted.

Comment: I think what the book is saying is that you can describe types for such patterns. For example a function that has properties on the function itself, like a constructor with static methods.

Comment: Sure, I get that - but why `c(10)` if I can't actually call `c` that way. Is there an intermediary step that's missing.

Comment: From what I understand the example is not meant to be run. `c` can be any object that adheres to that interface. It is just showing that you can do it. That's what I see anyway.

Comment: Ok, so there is a step missing - just wanted to clarify, I'm just starting to dive into Typescript - thank you for your help.

Comment: @elclanrs - if you're interested check out my answer below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To complete the example from the Typescript handbook:

```
interface Counter {
    (start: number): string;
    interval: number;
    reset(): void;
}

function createCounter():Counter{
    var counter = <Counter>function(start:number){};
    counter.interval = 123;
    counter.reset = function(){};
    return counter;
}

createCounter()(10);
createCounter().reset();
```

or

```
var getCounter = createCounter();
getCounter(10);
getCounter.reset();
```