# Typescript overwrite express send function with hybrid interface

Tags: express, typescript, hybrid

I'm trying to overwrite the node express `send` method of the `Response` type.
The method is of type `Send` that is defined as such:

```
interface Send {
    (status: number, body?: any): Response;
    (body?: any): Response;
}
```

My objective is to add local logging of the response send with express, but I can't make an implementation of this type, even as a function like explained in other questions [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25340601/typescript-hybrid-type-implementation).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That interface describes a function with two signatures, you can implement it like so:

```
const fn: Send = (first?: any, second?: any) => {
    if (first && second) {
        // deal with (status: number, body: any)
    } else if (first) {
        // deal with (status: number) or (body: any)
    } else {
        // deal with ()
    }

    return new Response();
}
```

Comment: Although technically correct, the `= (...) =>` format binds `this` to the current class in my setup, making it not work with express send function. Instead, I found and used [express-mung](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-mung), that achieves what I initially wanted to do.